# Можно ли удалить карту после оплаты Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play

Требуется оплатить аккаунт разработчика из России.
Если я привяжу карту, оплачу необходимую сумму, а потом отвяжу карту, то всё будет нормально или мне скажут, что нужна привязанная карта для аккаунта разработчика?

Comment: Почему бы не попробовать

Comment: Потому что у меня будет пару часов за которые другой человек даст мне данные своей карты в его личном присутствии, а потом карту нужно будет отвязать...

Comment: Ответ — да. После оплаты карточку можно тут же удалить. Страница с привязанными картами https://payments.google.com/gp/w/home/paymentmethods   Можете сами туда зайти и попробовать добавить свою карту и потом её удалить. Любые же оплаты **G.** сделанные на ходу с любой из карточек попадают туда. Если вам потом понадобится за что-то доплатить, то это можно сделать тем же методом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Так делать нельзя до окончательного подтверждения регистрации аккаунта разработчика.

Иначе платёжный профиль будет заблокирован и Google запросит фотографию или отсканированную копию карты с которой произведена оплата.

Карту можно удалять после окончания проверки всех документов.